# Is this Data Encryption/Storage Method Secure?

Tags: php, security, encryption, mcrypt

Let me first say that **I know it is a bad idea** to store sensitive information in a mysql database, so please don't respond by saying "DON'T DO IT" or something to that effect. I am building a website for which it is *absolutely essential* to store Social Security Numbers, and I have to be able to retrieve that data back out of the DB (no hashing).

That said, I have researched the best way to encrypt/decrypt the data, and built a custom function to handle the encryption. Here is my encrypting function:

```
function my_data_encrypt($value){
    $salt=substr(uniqid('', true), 0, 20);
    $key=$salt.MY_PRIVATE_KEY;
    $enc_value=base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $value, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));
    return array("enc_value"=>$enc_value, "salt"=>$salt);
}
```

So basically I am generating a random string for my salt, then appending to the salt a private key `MY_PRIVATE_KEY` which is defined in a separate config file. I then use `mcrypt_encrypt` to encrypt the data, then `base64_encode` to make the encryption safe to store in the DB. The encrypted string and the unique salt are then returned and stored in the DB together.

My thinking was that throwing a "private key" that is stored in the config file (not the DB) into the mix would add another level of security to the encryption, that way even if someone hacks the database and gets the encrypted value and the salt, they still wouldn't have everything they need to decrypt the data.

Can you security experts review my function and let me know if/how my data could be hacked and if there is anything else I could do to improve it?

**I have moved this question to https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35690/is-this-data-encryption-storage-method-secure . Thanks for your feedback.**

Comment: security.stackexchange.com

Comment: Also, http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

My two cents... Your random string isn't really random because you're using a time based function, instead consider [openssl_random_pseudo_bytes](http://php.net/openssl_random_pseudo_bytes)

Second, because you didn't explicitly mention it, you'll want to use [SSL/SSH](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.storage.php) for those types of data transactions.

As far as your private key, hopefully that config file is located outside of a publicly accessible directory and not in a shared environment.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will consider changing my salt generator. We are using an SSL, so the data transfer is secure. Also, the private key is not accessible to the public.

Comment: @BWDesign not accessible to the public? Or not in a publicly accessible directory (ie, stored outside of the web root)? Two different things ;)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I will make sure it is in a secure directory ;)

Comment: Since a salt only needs to be unique that shouldn't be a big issue.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `mcrypt_create_iv` instead of `md5(md5($key))` to generate the initialization vector. Store it with the ciphertext and salt.

```
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC));
$enc_value=base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $value, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
return array("enc_value"=>$enc_value, "salt"=>$salt, "iv"=>$iv);
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. I will look into that. Do you have any input as to how secure the overall script is? Do you know of any way that it could be hacked/decrypted?

Comment: I think changing to mcrypt_create_iv and Mister Martin's suggestions should make it pretty solid. The security will be dependent on the encryption key and its storage.

Comment: If you use a per-message salt, you don't need an IV anymore.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: True, but using `md5(md5($key))` is not useful at all. Especially to people who are reading this later as a learning tool.